# Angular + Firestore "update" call loses input focus

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

When I lose focus on an input field (onBlur), I  want to update the Firestore database with the newly inputted value. The functionality of the code works just fine. The data gets updated in Firestore. However, if I jump from one input to another, I lose focus on the newly focused input right away because Angular is working in the background to update the Firestore DB with the value of the previously focused input. This provides a poor user experience as the user is forced to click in the input field a second time to give it focus again :

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? Can this be fixed? Here is a snippet of the code used :

**HTML :**

```html
<e-column field='comment' headerText='NOTES' textAlign='Left'>
  <ng-template #template let-data>
    <input #commentField
           type="text"
           (blur)="updateInputField(data.id, $event.target.value)"
           value="{{data.comment}}" />
  </ng-template>
</e-column>
```

**TYPESCRIPT :**

```js
updateInputField(id: string, value: string) {
    this.afs.collection('GRD_active').doc(id).update({ comment: value });
}
```

Thanks to all for your support!

Comment: Instead of binding to the input's blur event, have you tried using reactive forms and their valueChanges Observables?

Comment: I tested this with vanilla inputs and the focus worked as expected. Maybe it's something related to an external library you use to display or add additional functionality to your inputs. In order to troubleshoot this, it might be useful to see where the focus is going with `document.activeElement`

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same problem. Basically your update is re-rendering your block of inputs.

You just need to implement the trackBy function for your for loop and that's it.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of collection;trackBy: trackByFn">
</div>

trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; 
}
```

You can get more information at: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5